# Нужно ли школьников учить правильно читать текст

Tags: недопустимая-метка

С точки зрения фонетики, наша речь произносится с определенной интонацией.

Например, с помощью ПАУЗ  различной длительности текст делится на отдельные речевые отрезки, ПОВЫШЕНИЕ ТОНА  свидетельствует о незаконченности темы, а ПОНИЖЕНИЕ ТОНА делается в конце предложения или части сложного предложения. С помощью ЛОГИЧЕСКОГО УДАРЕНИЯ можно изменить его мелодику, подчеркнув особо важные слова. Умение правильно прочитать текст составляет часть актерского мастерства.

Правильно составленный текст легко читается и записывается, а неправильный - не читается и не записывается вовсе. Может быть, не все с этим согласятся, но знаки пунктуации можно практически "считать" с "правильного" текста.

Что же касается непосредственной практики письма, то постановку знаков вообще не принято соотносить с мелодикой предложения. Поэтому мы и воспринимаем письменную и устную речь как не связанные друг с другом, но правильно ли это?

И  ВОПРОСЫ:

Мелодика чтения хотя в каком-то объеме изучается в школе? Как детей учат правильно и красиво читать, есть ли для этого какие-то технические приемы, особые методы? Или это для школьной практики вещь совершенно ненужная?

Answer (score 1):

Учат ли детей правильно читать? Да, это называется чтение с выражением. Не могу говорить про ФГОСы, но поощряется подобное чтение точно. Для выразительного чтения лучше всего подходит метод Станиславского (вжиться в роль лирического героя и читать от его лица), но не припомню, чтобы в школе о нём кто-то прямо упоминал. Другое дело, что разбирая стихотворения и историю его создания ученик узнаёт больше о целях автора, что должно облегчить попадание в образ. Что касается теоретических знаний о повышении и понижении тона, то для носителя языка без филологического образования они излишни, говорить он всё равно будет так же как окружающий его социум.